# jquery getting value on specific dynamic `<td>`

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a page like this (i dont have enough point to post image, so i put on other host)

http://i47.tinypic.com/akixx2.jpg

what i want is when user click delete then jquery can find the specific email. for example when user click delete on John's row then jquery can find value of his email.

this is my html:

```
<table class="table">
    {foreach $query as $value}
    <tr>
        <td>{$value@iteration}</td>
        <td>{$value.buyer_un}</td>
        <td id="delete{$value@iteration}">{$value.buyer_email}</td>
        <td>{$value.buyer_address}</td>
        <td>{$value.buyer_create_date}</td>
        <td>{$value.buyer_status}</td>
        <td>
            <a id="delete{$value@iteration}" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {/foreach}
    </table>
```

and this is my jquery which is fail:

```
<script>
$("a[id*='delete']").click(function(){
    var selected=$('td:eq(2)',this).val();
    $.post("{#siteUrl#}superuser/proses",{literal}{del:"TRUE",email:selected}{/literal}, function(data)
    {
        $(".modal-body").html(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `delete` class to `a` then add the email address to a `data-` on the `a`. So you could do the following:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
     var email = $(this).attr('data-email');
     //ajax to php to delete.
});
```

ID's are singular, meaning only one. Classes, are multiple.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$("a[id*='delete']").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var selected = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
    //ajax request
});
```

Hope this helps.